# Ordenação dos dados com prioridade de valor utilizando LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Possuo uma tabela de "status" com os seguintes valores:

```
ID 1 = Ativo 
ID 2 = Novo
ID 3 = Excluido
```

Como faria para retornar uma lista de objetos (que possuem o objeto status) priorizando, vindo por primeiro, os que possuem Status 2 (Novo) utilizando LINQ?

Gostaria de saber se tem uma solução melhor do que fazer com duas (2) Lista.

Answer (score 5):

Seria algo assim:

```
var lista = contexto.Entidade
                    .Where(/* Sua condição aqui */)
                    .OrderBy(e => e.Status == 2)
                    .ThenBy(e => e.Status)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var lista = contexto.Entidade.Where(/*Alguma condição*/) 
                             .OrderBy(e => e.Status.Id == 2) //Ordenar primeiramente pelo status com id = 2
                             .ThenBy(e => e.Status.Id) //Depois ordenar pelo id dos status em ordem crescente
                             .ToList(); //Converter para List
```